# How to Work with Nunits using Dataaccess layer and taking connection string from config file?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How to Work with Nunits(unit testing) using Dataaccess layer and connection string from config file?

Answer (score 2):

Integration testing of databases from NUnit and any other unit testing framework is a topic that comes up from time to time. I've written about it several times, most recently here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/01/31/dataaccesscomponenttestingredux.aspx